# Problema con aparición de Undefined en un bucle

Tags: javascript

Me estoy encontrando con un error al intentar hacer una clasificación de una carrera:

```
let clasificaciones = ["Ana", "Raul", "Celia", "Marias", "Antonio"];

const mostrarClasificacion = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < clasificaciones.length; i++) {
    document.write(i + 1  + "- " + clasificaciones[i] + "<br>");
  }
};

document.write(mostrarClasificacion());
```

Lo que me pasa es que al imprimir la posición de `"Antonio"` también me imprime abajo un `"Undefined"` y ya revisé por si hay problemas con el array o el bucle y no me estaría dando cuenta del error.

Comment: Porque estas poniendo 2 veces `document.write`. Para llamar a una funcion solo es con su nombre, en este caso `mostrarClasificacion()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El undefined es por esta linea

```
document.write(mostrarClasificacion());
```

Aquí le estás diciendo que escriba en el `document` lo que regresa la función `mostrarCalificación()`, pero esa función solo escribe en el documento, no retorna nada.

Cambia esa linea por simplemente

```
let clasificaciones = ["Ana", "Raul", "Celia", "Marias", "Antonio"];
    
    const mostrarClasificacion = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < clasificaciones.length; i++) {
        document.write(i + 1  + "- " + clasificaciones[i] + "<br>");
      }
    };

mostrarClasificacion();
```

Si quieres entender un poco más, agrega esto.

```
   let clasificaciones = ["Ana", "Raul", "Celia", "Marias", "Antonio"];
    
    const mostrarClasificacion = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < clasificaciones.length; i++) {
        document.write(i + 1  + "- " + clasificaciones[i] + "<br>");
      }
      return 'data retornada'
    };

document.write(mostrarClasificacion());
```

Al hacer esto, entonces como la función retorna una cadena de texto, al escribir `document.write(mostrarClasificacion());` la última linea cambiará por `data retornada` en vez de undefined

Comment: Funciono jaja muchas gracias, no había caído en que estaba usando el document al pedo xd.